# Connecting QT Form events to Function

Tags: python, pyqt4

I am attempting to make a simple QT user-form interface.  I am having trouble connecting user-form events to a function.  The function is operational but I cannot seem to connect it to a user-form event.  I have attempted both ways as explained here: http://zetcode.com/gui/pyqt4/eventsandsignals/  See code snippets below.

### Attempt at Connecting

```
    #Connect Form Events to Functions
    QtCore.QObject.connect(self.dlg.radioButton, QtCore.SIGNAL('toggled()'), self.enableOne)
    #self.dlg.radioButton.toggled.connect(self.enableOne)
    self.dlg.radioButton_2.toggled.connect(self.enableTwo) 
    self.dlg.radioButton_3.toggled.connect(self.enableThree)
```

### Function Definitions

```
def enableOne(self):
    if self.dlg.radioButton.isChecked() == True:
        self.dlg.pointButton.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.dlg.pointButton.setEnabled(False)  
##Use point later as point(s)-of-origin
def enableTwo(self):
    if self.dlg.radioButton_2.isChecked() == True:
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.dlg.comboBox_2.setEnabled(False)                     
##Input Latitude and Longitude
def enableThree(self):  
    if self.dlg.radioButton_3.isChecked() == True:
        self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setEnabled(True)
        self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setEnabled(True)
    else:
        self.dlg.lineEdit_2.setEnabled(False)
        self.dlg.lineEdit_3.setEnabled(False)
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code looks correct, try to post better example:
[How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

You can try my short code, where signals working correctly:

```
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore

class Window(QtGui.QMainWindow):

    def __init__(self):
        super(Window, self).__init__()
        self.setGeometry(50, 50, 500, 300)

        self.rb1 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button1", self)
        self.rb1.setGeometry(100, 50, 200, 20)
        self.rb1.toggled.connect(self.one)
        self.rb2 = QtGui.QRadioButton("button2", self)
        self.rb2.setGeometry(100,100, 200, 20)
        self.rb2.toggled.connect(self.two)

        self.lbl1 = QtGui.QLabel("text", self)
        self.lbl1.setGeometry(100,150, 200, 20)

    def one(self):
        self.lbl1.setText("one")

    def two(self):
        self.lbl1.setText("two")


app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
GUI = Window()
GUI.show()
sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

hope this will help